# no applicable method of tibble when passed to a function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I'm trying to pass a tibble to a function call and then perform some dplyr transformations on it. However, when I pass the tibble to the function it tells me that I cannot perform `mutate` on an object of class character.

For example, say I have this data and this code:

```
dataframe_1 <- tibble(var1 = c('a','b','c','d'), var2 = c('e','f','g','h'))
dataframe_2 <- tibble(var1 = c(1,2,3,4), var2 = c(5,6,7,8))
dataframe_3 <- tibble(var1 = c('i','j','k','l'), var2 = c('m','n','o','p'))
dataframe_4 <- tibble(var1 = c(9,10,11,12), var2 = c(13,14,15,16)) 


function_name <- function(.x) {
  .x %>%
  mutate(var3 = .x)
}
  
print_table <- map_dfr(
  .x = dataframe_1,
  .f = function_name
)
```

I get the error `Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"`.

But if I run this:

```
function_name <- function(.x) {
  return(.x)
}

print_table <- map_dfr(
  .x = dataframe_1,
  .f = function_name
)
```

I get

```
print_table
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  var1  var2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     e    
2 b     f    
3 c     g    
4 d     h
```

So R is able to tell that `dataframe_1` is in fact a tibble, and I know that it's possible to pipe tibbles into a `mutate()` command.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong here?

Comment: What is your expected?  It is not clear why you need `map`.  The object looped over the `map` is a vector or column, and it cannot do the `mutate` on that vector

Comment: In this toy example the expected output is just a version of the tibble that's been passed to the function with a new column called `var3` which contains the name of the tibble (in this case "`dataframe_1`"). I think i'm using `map` because ultimately I want to be able to pass all four dataframes to the function call and perform the same transformation on each of them. Thanks!

Comment: If that is the case, you may need `lst(dataframe_1, dataframe_2, dataframe_3) %>% imap(~ .x %>% mutate(var3 = .y))`

Comment: Basically, your function and the map input is not correct.  Please check the solution below

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are creating the object name as a column, get all the objects (`mget`) into a named `list` based on the `pattern` in the object names created in `ls`, then loop over the `list` with `imap`, and create the column from the names using `.y`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = 'dataframe_\\d+')) %>% 
    imap(~ .x %>%
                 mutate(var3 = .y))
```

Comment: Quick follow-up: do you know how I can return each of the objects bound together into a single df? I.e. the above produces four separate tibbles. I've tried `all_dfs <- tibble(mget(ls(pattern = ....) %>% ....)` but that returns an empty tibble

Comment: @C.Robin You can use `imap_dfr` if we want to rbind them together instead of just `imap`

Comment: That's done the trick. Thanks again